# Can Ruby Open a file, Find a keyword or words then write text after that line?

Tags: ruby

I am about a week or so into Ruby development and I was wondering if there was a way to read in a file, locate a specific sentence and then after that sentence write another line of text.

For instance if I asked the program to locate this line "hello, how are today?". What would I need to do to output "I am great, how are you" in the same file but on the next line.

I.E. in *.txt

```
#Hello, how are you?
```

becomes this in *.txt

```
#Hello, how are you?
#I am great, how are you?
```

The research I have done has allowed me to find;

```
File.readlines("FILE_NAME").each{ |line| print line if line =~ /check_String/ }
```

Which returns specific keywords and this one which changes a word to something else.

```
def ChangeOnFile(file, regex_to_find, text_to_put_in_place)
  text= File.read file
  File.open(file, 'w+'){|f| f << text.gsub(regex_to_find, text_to_put_in_place)}
end

ChangeOnFile('*.txt', /hello/ , "goodbye")
```

If anyone has a link to a tutorial that could help me or anything that would help me understand what needs to be done then I would be quite a happy camper.

Thank you kindly

Comment: I added code blocks and also removed the Rails tag, since this is just a plain Ruby question.

Comment: @user652368: I noticed your .txt file contents example weren't displaying per line (like you typed it) so I modified it to use the code formatting and put a '#' at the beginning of each line so that it won't have weird coloring.

Answer (score 5):

Since you might be adding to the middle of the file you're going to have to build a new one. Using [Tempfile](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/classes/Tempfile.html) is very helpful for this type of thing as you can build it temporarily and then replace the original using [FileUtils](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/classes/FileUtils.html). You have a couple options without using regular expressions as shown below. I also included a regular expression example too. I've verified that this code works on Ruby 1.9.2.

**The code:**

```
require 'tempfile'
require 'fileutils'

file_path = 'C:\Users\matt\RubymineProjects\test\sample.txt'
line_to_find = 'Hello, how are you?'
line_to_add = 'I am great, how are you?'

temp_file = Tempfile.new(file_path)

begin
  File.readlines(file_path).each do |line|
    temp_file.puts(line)
    temp_file.puts(line_to_add) if line.chomp == line_to_find

    #or... if you just want to see if a given line contains the
    #sentence you are looking for you can:
    #temp_file.puts(line_to_add) if line.include?(line_to_find)

    #or... using regular expressions:
    #temp_file.puts(line_to_add) if line =~ /Hello, how are you/
  end
  temp_file.close
  FileUtils.mv(temp_file.path,file_path)
ensure
  temp_file.delete
end
```

**Original sample.txt** (minus the # symbols):

```
#This line should not be found.
#Hello, how are you?
#Inserted Line should go before this one.
```

**After running script** (minus the # symbols):

```
#This line should not be found.
#Hello, how are you?
#I am great, how are you?
#Inserted Line should go before this one.
```